# Unable to access git over https

Tags: git, https

I have put this in **`httpd.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:17501>
ServerName my.server.com
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/opt/git/repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core*">
   Options ExecCGI Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to make it https accessible over the port `17501` and the path for repository is `/var/opt/git/repos`.

Should i make any other changes? Any ideas?